replacing the active capture on the page PAY_NOW?
Is it possible to actively pull orders to be captured by receiving CHECKOUT.ORDER.APPROVED events and scheduled tasks to capture, Replace the capture of active calls to the backend interface on the PAY_NOW page?
yes/no?？

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
